# Proving $\mathrm{Hom}(V \rightarrow W)$ is a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra

It can easily be proven that $\newcommand{\Hom}{\mathrm{Hom}}\Hom(V \rightarrow W)$ is a sub-space.

**1.** we know that for any $T:V\rightarrow W$, T(0)=0, therefore $0\in \Hom(V \rightarrow W)$

**2.** for $H=\Hom(V \rightarrow W)$, $H(\alpha*v_1+v_2)=\alpha*H(v_1)+H(v_2)\in \Hom(V \rightarrow W)$

Therefore $\Hom(V \rightarrow W)$ is a sub-space. The question is if it is sufficient to show that something is a sub-space and to conclude about it that it also a vector space?

Comment: I am confused, what vector space do you think $\operatorname{Hom}(V \to W)$ is a subspace of? The elements of $\operatorname{Hom}(V\to W)$ are maps, not elements of $V$ or of $W$.

Comment: the question in general is if prove something is a subspace$\implies$ vector space?

Comment: @angryavian's point is that you seemed to be confused as to what a subspace is. You seem to be trying to show that the vector space axioms hold, which they do, so just show it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to show that the [axioms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space#Definition) of a vector space are satisfied. The "vectors" are now the linear maps from $V$ to $W$, and the scalars are the same as in $V$ and $W$.

Here are some of them. Note that many of the properties are inherited from $V$ and $W$, so many of the axioms hold immediately.

- Additive identity: If $T_0$ is the zero map ($T_0(v)=0$ for all $v \in V$), then $T+T_0 = T$ for any $T \in \operatorname{Hom}(V\to W)$.
- Commutativity of addition: If $T_1, T_2 \in \operatorname{Hom}(V \to W)$, then $T_1+T_2=T_2+T_1$ because $$(T_1+T_2)(v)\equiv T_1(v)+T_2(v)=T_2(v)+T_1(v)\equiv (T_2+T_1)(v).$$

---

With regard to your comment:

By definition, a [subspace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_subspace) is itself a vector space, but moreover it lives inside a larger vector space. Your work above does not show that $\operatorname{Hom}(V\to W)$ is a subspace because you have not specified what the larger space is (even disregarding other issues with your work).